# Qt5 memory usage depends on window size?

Tags: c++, qt, window, mingw, qt5

I am new to Qt so maybe this is just stupid issue ...

I have simple demo-Application. 
main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

and mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}
```

When I start the application, the memory usage is about 2MB ... when I maximize the window the usage is about 10MB. Why does this happen and how to solve this? I thought Qt uses WinAPI to create windows?

P.S. I use static build of Qt (release build not debug)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a memory leak, bigger windows requires more drawing, which requires more memory to draw. It's a bit more noticeable with Qt5 as much of the drawing has been moved over to OpenGL which is a bit more greedy with memory.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this may be at least partially caused by double-buffering (the larger the window, the bigger region to buffer).

10 MB is not a lot of memory these days, so if you know you don't have any memory leak, just don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Qt Problem.

Open notepad++ and maximize it, you will see the memory usage is higher.

Comment: 2021, I don't see that in notepad++, discord, photoshop, vs code, pretty much every application anymore. They must be doing something different now?